# Is InboundJaxrsResponse an error?

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I am implementing RESTful services using Jersey and on the post method I am getting

> InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=POST,
>   uri=https://dev-osb.int.mgc.com/ESignature/Docusign/DEV1/DocuSignRestSendDocuments,
>   status=200, reason=OK}}

So for sure I am not getting the right response back and I am confuse if this is causing it. Below is the post method.

```
WebTarget webTarget = client.createResource( ESignatureSpringUtil.getMessage( KeyConstants.ALSB_DOCUSIGN_ADDRESS )
                + ESignatureSpringUtil.getMessage( KeyConstants.REST_SEND_DOCUMENTS_ADDRESS ) );

        Invocation.Builder builder = webTarget
                .request( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE )
                .header( KeyConstants.REST_URI_APPENDERS, docSb )
                .header( DocusignRESTContants.CONTENT_TYPE, DocusignRESTContants.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA )
                .header( DocusignRESTContants.X_DOCUSIGN_AUTHENTICATION, getDocusignAuthHeader( cu ) );

        Response response = builder.post( Entity.entity( multiPart.toString().getBytes(), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM ), Response.class );
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand. did you mean after hitting you get the response in the format which you don't expect ? if yes then in what format u want?

Comment: So, I am assuming there are two issues. One is that I am not quite sure about the fact that I need to pass multipart as a byte because I am already marshaling it. So if I pass just multipart as a plain java object I get MessageBodyWriter Exception. But, if I pass multipart as a byte stream the response becomes InboundJaxrsResponse with 200 status code but I don't get any emails that I am suppose to meaning it doesn't work.

Comment: Its not an error. It's a subclass of Response. What makes you think it's error?

Comment: I just got that too peeskillet. Actually in Jersey 1.x after the post request I get an email from the vendor but here I am not. I was thinking if I am not building a proper post request.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer. So instead of passing the multipart as a byte stream I passed it as a plain java object rather and I had to set the media type on the multipart like multipart.setMediaType("application/whatever"). Then on the entity method get the media type from the multipart. So now it is generating email.**